# ASP.net Recover JavaScript Created Attribute from PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I've create a control that derivates from a TextBox. On that class is added an call for a Javascript code that, when the content of the text changes, it adds a attribute called "post" with value "true" to the control. I wish to collect that value.

So far i have this:

**ASP**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CWEB.Web.UI.USR.DefPage" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Controls" Namespace="CWEB.Web.Controls" Assembly="Web" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetPost(element){if(!element.hasAttribute('post')){z=document.createAttribute('post');z.value='true';element.setAttributeNode(z);}else{element.setAttribute('post','true');}}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <Controls:TextBox runat="server" ID="abc" />
</body>
</html>
```

**CodeBehind (and TextBox derivated class)**

```
using SysWeb = global::System.Web.UI;
using CtrWeb = global::CWEB.Web.Controls;
namespace CWEB.Web
{
    internal static class Binder
    {
        internal const string PostableKey = "post";
        internal const string AuxFieldKey = "_ck";
        internal static bool GetCheck(string ck) { return (ck != null && ck != "" && (ck == global::CWEB.Data.Fields.Boolean.ValueTrue || ck.Contains("t") || ck.Contains("v"))); }

        private static bool GetCheckInput(CtrWeb.Controls.Generic.FieldControl Control, ref bool Found)
        {
            if (Control == null || Control.Page == null) { Found = false; }
            else
            {
                string value = Control.Page.Request.Form[Control.ClientID + CtrWeb.Binder.AuxFieldKey]; //If then it's child is null, it means it's unchecked.
                Found = (value != null && value != "");
                return ((Found) ? (value == "1" || value == "on" || value.Contains("t")) : false);
            }
            return false;
        }

        internal static bool GetCheck(CtrWeb.Controls.Generic.FieldControl Control, bool OutSideInput, string ViewStateKey = CtrWeb.Binder.CheckAttribute)
        {
            string value = Control.Page.Request.Form[Control.UniqueID]; //If the main control exists then it's child shal too.
            if (value == null || value == "") { return CtrWeb.Binder.GetCheck((string)Control.GetViewState()[ViewStateKey]); }
            else if (OutSideInput)
            {
                bool Found = false;
                return CtrWeb.Binder.GetCheckInput(Control, ref Found);
            } else { return CtrWeb.Binder.GetCheck((string)Control.GetAttributes()[ViewStateKey]); }
        }

        internal static void SetCheck(CtrWeb.Controls.Generic.FieldControl Control, bool OutSideInput, string ViewStateKey = CtrWeb.Binder.CheckAttribute)
        {
            bool FValue = CtrWeb.Binder.GetCheck(Control, OutSideInput, ViewStateKey: ViewStateKey);
            Control.GetViewState()[ViewStateKey] = ((FValue) ? "true" : "false");
        }
    }

    namespace Controls
    {
        public interface FieldControl
        {
            string ClientID { get; }
            string UniqueID { get; }
            SysWeb.Page Page { get; }
            SysWeb.AttributeCollection GetAttributes();
            SysWeb.StateBag GetViewState();
        }

        public class TextBox : SysWeb.WebControls.TextBox, CtrWeb.FieldControl
        {
            public bool Postable
            {
                get { return CtrWeb.Binder.GetCheck(this, false, ViewStateKey: CtrWeb.Binder.PostableKey); }
                set { CtrWeb.Binder.SetCheck(this, false, ViewStateKey: CtrWeb.Binder.PostableKey); }
            }

            protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
            {
                this.BaseLoadViewState(savedState);
                this.Postable = CtrWeb.Binder.GetCheck(this, false, ViewStateKey: CtrWeb.Binder.PostableKey);
            }

            protected override void OnInit(global::System.EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    this.Attributes.Add("onchange", "SetPost(this)");
                    this.Attributes.Add(MdWeb.Binder.PostableKey, "false");
                }
                base.OnInit(e);
            }
        }
    }

    namespace UI.USR
    {
        public class DefPage : SysWeb.Page { protected CtrWeb.TextBox abc; }
    }
}
```

Some codes were not copied here because they have nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for that data to be posted to the server, you have to store it in a form value.

HTML elements in their entirety aren't posted to the server.  Only the key/value pairs of form elements are.  (WebForms is trying to *trick you* into thinking that the *whole page* is posted to the server, but it's a lie.)

Add a hidden form field to the page, something as simple as this:

```
<asp:Hidden id="someHiddenField" />
```

Then in the JavaScript, set the value of that field:

```
document.getElementById('<%= someHiddenField.ClientID %>').value = 'true';
```

Then when the page posts back to the server, the `'true'` value will be in that hidden field:

```
someHiddenField.Value
```

Comment: i get it, but it works on other attributes that i declare and change, as long as they are declared before the postback. Why is that?

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: Can you provide a more complete example of something that "works" vs. one that doesn't?

Comment: i'll try some modifications on ViewState - i really can't use a hiddenfield for that - i'd have hundreds of hiddenfields generated that way if i do.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: Weren't there going to be hundreds of controls anyway?  I suppose you could have a single field with a JSON serialized object as its value.  Each client-side modification would grab the JSON in the field, update the structure, and write it back to the field.

Comment: i see it david, but i'd have to have 1 hiddenfield for each textbox and dropbox in the page - it would double it's size and i wouldn't like that. i want to do something more simple, exactly like the embeded attributes that the .Net already have - for instance, how the textbox get the "text" property typed by the user? when it changes on client size what happens? i want a more "native" behavior.

Comment: how does the asp.net TextBox do it with it's own properties?

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: What "embedded attributes"?  The `text` property is sent by the browser to the server as part of the POST request, that's how the server gets that value.  It doesn't send anything else.  "Native behavior" would be that if you want more values posted from the form them you add more form elements.  (Or, somewhat more manually, add a single form element with a serialized structure of values.)

Comment: oh, i get it then - it's not loaded because it's not sent on the POST method... i see, so the POST method would not send all atributes of all controls, only the one that responds on the "Form[string]" method? i get it then, i know what to do... i'm looking at the "void LoadViewState(object savedState)" of the control. The "Text" value is not defined yet, so i can get the value that WAS on the viewstate, let it load the value from post and compare to determinate if it changed at all... thanks

Comment: now i just need to figure out betwenn "LoadViewState" on the control and the moment that i get's the POST content to update the ViewState.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: This sounds like you're going to end up drastically over-complicating things.  Complex things are fragile and are a great place for bugs to quietly hide.  If there's some piece of data you want to send from the client to the server, put it in a form field.  If you're worried about the performance of many fields then there are ways to optimize that.  (Use a single field of serialized values, minimize the footprint of those values, use bitmasks to store many booleans in a single numeric value, etc.)  Adding a value to a form is simple.  What you're doing is complex.

Comment: Thank you for your advises David. But i don't really need that boolean field i figured. What i want is to know if the value changed since the last post back. To do that i could use the Change event, but i have a bad experience with it, since i would need to be sure that it would trigger first - before any other event on the page. I'll just write a comparition on "bool LoadPostData(postDataKey, postCollection)" override and se the Postable property True or False. Easy as that. I understand your worry.

Answer (score 0):

asp:Hidden doesn't exist. only form elements can actually postback data. The server side will take the postback data and load it into the form element provided that the runat=server is set.

in markup or html:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="txtHiddenDestControl" />
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtHiddenDestControl.ClientID %>').value = '1';
```

code behind:

```
string postedVal = txtHiddenDestControl.Value.ToString();
```